# Does anyone have a function to add escape characters to a plain text string so that it can be treated as verbatim in a regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

Does anyone have an existing, proven javascript method that will convert a plain text string to its equivalent regex string, with escapes ('\' added for all of the regex control characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common overlooked problem.  I hope this routine helps.

```
   /** add escapes for regexp special characters to turn plainText into a verbatim regexp string
    *
    * @param plainText plain text string that may contain characters that need to be escaped to become a regexp
    * @returns {string} modified string that will work within a regexp
    */
   regexpEscape: function (plainText) {
       //noinspection JSLint
       return plainText.replace(/([-()\[\]{}+?*.$\^|,:#<!\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
   },
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for; you are such a genius.  I'll try it out and hopefully it will fill the bill.

Comment: you can shorten your pattern with: `text.replace(/(?=[()[{+?*.^$|\\])/g, '\\')` (note: all other characters don't need to be escaped)

Comment: You must add the delimiter to the class: `\/`

Comment: plainText.replace(/([-()\[\]{}+?*.$\^|,:#<!\/\\])/g, '\\$1')

Comment: edited as per comments. Thank you.